# SQL Server 2005, SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, distinct

How can I modify this query to return distinct `Models` and `VideoProcessor` columns ?

```
SELECT TOP(20) * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       [3D_Benchmarks].Id AS BenchmarkId,
       Manufacturer, Model, Slug, VideoProcessor, 
       FPS, CPU 
    FROM 
       [3D_Benchmarks]
   JOIN 
       [3D_Slugs] ON [3D_Benchmarks].Id = [3D_Slugs].BenchmarkId) AS tb 
ORDER BY 
   tb.FPS DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

New answer based on your comment.  This looks up the twenty highest FPS Model+VideoProcessor.  For each of those, it picks the row with the highest FPS.

```
select  details.Model
,       details.VideoProcessor
,       details.FPS
,       <add other columns here>
from    (
        select  top 20 b.Model
        ,       VideoProcessor
        from    [3D_Benchmarks] b
        join    [3D_Slugs] s
        on      b.Id = s.BenchmarkId 
        group by
                b.Model
        order by
                max(b.FPS) desc
        ) top20
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    [3D_Benchmarks[ b
        join    [3D_Slugs] s
        on      b.Id = s.BenchmarkId 
        where   b.Model = top20.Model
                and b.VideoProcessor = top20.VideoProcessor
        order by
                b.FPS desc
        ) details
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns only two columns. I need all the above columns with these two distinct (model and videoprocessor), I don't know how to combine this query with my query

Comment: Say there are two rows with Model = '3000' and VideoProcessor = 'AwesomeGpu', one with 100 FPS and one with 50 FPS.  Which FPS value would you like to display?

Comment: I want to display the top 20 with the highest fps, but not the same mode with the same videoprocessor

Comment: @Mario M: Edited answer based on your comment

Comment: I get this error: 
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.
    Incorrect syntax near '3'.

Comment: again...ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'details'.

Comment: Answer edited again (in a hurry so I can't test), hope it helps, otherwise comment the error message!